# Can't update wsl even when running PowerShell as admin

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, elevation

I'm trying to update my default WSL distribution and even though I'm running PowerShell as an admin I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: have you run powershell as admin - I know it sounds absurd, but try that

Comment: That's what I did, you can see on the top of the window (`Administrator: Windows PowerShell`)

Comment: I can start powershell as the  user Administrator, it doesn't necessarily run with full Admin privileges - that's why I said "it sounds absurb" - i.e. click Start, search for powershell, right click the result and select "run as admin"

Comment: This is what I did.

Comment: fair enough, its not always obvious :p

Answer (score 0):

It'd seem like you don't have full admin credentials for the endpoint.
I myself saw it being caused by a disabled UAC window ( which then ran the terminal as admin without abitily to actually run commands as an administrator ) but it might occur by many causes.

I'd recommend using the following links to bypass or fix the issue:
You can see a way to bypass that alongside a useful script to check if you're actually running with administrative rights:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990822/running-as-ps-as-admin-but-receive-error-that-operation-requires-elevation

Or just running an administrative powershell windows from powershell:

```
 # Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
 $myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
 $myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
  
 # Get the security principal for the Administrator role
 $adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
  
 # Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
 if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    clear-host
    }
 else
    {
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
    
    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
    
    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
    
    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
    
    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
    
    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
    }
  
 wsl --update
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/a-self-elevating-powershell-script

Comment: This doesn't work. The first call returns `True`, then I use the 2nd one it asks for elevation still.

Comment: Can you try to make sure `Receive updates for other Microsoft products whern you update Windows` is enabled under Windows Update advanced-settings?